# Finding the eqn. of a plane that passes through the line of intersection of 2 planes and is perpendicular to another plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the equation of the plane that passes through the line of intersection of the planes $4x - 2y + z - 3 = 0$ and $2x - y + 3z + 1 = 0$, and that is perpendicular to the plane $3x + y - z + 7 = 0$.

I have attached a picture and that is what I got.

Can someone please tell me if my answer is right because the answer at the back of the textbook is different but I am pretty confident with my solution. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If the proposed answer is $2x+3y+16z+14=0$, then it should not be right. For it is not perpendicular to the plane $3x+y-z+7=0$.

Comment: One problem is that you have a $+2$ instead of a $-2$ in the second row of the top leftmost matrix, so the line equation is incorrect. The $z$ component should be $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of the two planes gives a solution $(x,2(x-1),-1)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $n$ is the normal for our plane, then we need $n \bot (3,1,-1)$ (and $n \neq 0$). This gives $3 n_1+n_2=n_3 = 0$.

The plane will have the form $\langle n, (x,y,z) \rangle = \alpha$. Since the line is on the plane, we have $\langle n, (x,2(x-1),-1) \rangle = \alpha$ for all $x$. Differentiating gives $n_1+2 n_2 = 0$.

Solving gives $n = t(-2,1,-5)$ for some $t \neq 0$. I will pick $t=1$ to get $n=(-2,1,-5)$. Setting $x=0$ gives a point on the line as $(0,-2,-1)$ from which we get $\alpha = 3$.

Hence one equation of the plane is $-2x+y-5z = 3$.

Comment: hey, the matrix should have had a -2 in it instead of 2, thx a lot!